# Bugs when trying to play 'Battleswarm: Field of Honor' through Wine

Tags: wine

I am currently attempting to play *Battleswarm: Field of Honor* through a Wine in Ubuntu. While the installation was successful, the in-game stuff was riddled with bugs for me, preventing me to play at all.

1. No sound (occasional volume spikes but then stops later).
2. No mouse cursor (needless to say the cursor in game has vanished).
3. Unable so see ground, sky, or player models, replaced by useless color... (also splits game screen into 4 sections).

Proposed solutions are:

1. Install DirectX 9 through Wine and Winetricks (need help installing that...)
2. Turn off screen graphics (did nothing)
3. Update to a Wine version of 1.3 to fix cursor problem (currently mine is 1.2)

Now if someone can give me a few pointers, that would be great.

Comment: Ahh cool you took my advice and came here. I'll try to troubleshoot the problem now ^^! And welcome btw.

Comment: can you add your graphics card info? Btw for your sound: sound is problematic with WINE and Battleswarm + Pulseaudio, so you might just have to go without. You could optionally set your WINE output to esound or OSS btw. I have had mixed success with them.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install winetricks, `open a terminal( Ctrl + Alt + T ) and paste this  :

   `sudo apt-get install winetricks`
2. Use winetricks to install the required libraries

   `winetricks directx9 vcrun2005 vcrun2008 allfonts allcodecs`

NOTE : if you have a trouble when install xvid from koepi, open your winetricks and edit this part :

`gksu gedit /usr/bin/winetricks`

edit this part

> load_xvid()
>   {
>    w_call vcrun6
>    bla...bla...bla...
>   }

edit path download and md5 with this
 `w_download http://www.koepi.info/Xvid-1.3.2-20110601.exe b1bbd74395a34ff7fd069d3b6fe23016`

```
`cd "$W_CACHE"/xvid`

 `w_try $WINE Xvid-1.3.2-20110601.exe $W_UNATTENDED_SLASH_SILENT`
```

NOTE2 : if you install wine1.2 or wine1.3, winetricks is included, so you just need to type winetricks (list app you want to install), ex :

`winetricks directx9 vcrun2005 vcrun2008 allfonts allcodecs`